# Extract Lotus Notes Document's complete ACL from Java

Tags: java, document, acl, lotus-domino, lotus

I'm trying to find a way to save the complete user list access privileges for a specific lotus notes document.

I know I can get database-level ACL's from catalog.nsf, but not document-level access.  Also the Author field of the document -I believe- won't list read-only access users.

Does anyone know how to obtain the complete ACL of every user for a specific document?

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Edit: spelling.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simon is correct.  It is non-trivial.  Even though I would skip his suggestion of reading the Forms, it is still non-trivial.  Even for checking just a single document as per your question, it is non-trivial.  I know auditors sometimes want exactly this type of information, but Domino's security system wasn't designed with that in mind, and there's no built-in API to get the info.

In Java, you need to use the `Document.getItems()` method to retrieve a vector of all Items.  Then you have to look through the Items.  You need to check `Item.getType()` to determine if it is a `Item.READERS` or `Item.AUTHORS`.  If it is, then you need to do `Item.getValues()` to retrieve the vector of values, and you have to loop through the vector check to see if each value is a role.  If it is a role, you have to use `Database.getACL()` and iterate through the `ACLEntries` to determine which ones have the role and whether they are Person entries or Group entries.  And if they are group entries you have to look up the group members in the Domino Directory -- which might require expanding nested groups.  For any values in the Item that are not roles, you have check that value against the Domino Directory to see if it is a valid Person or Group -- and again expand the group until you finally get to the People.  For the lookups in the Domino Directory you have to worry about the fact that Directory Assistance may be configured in which case there can be multiple Domino Directory databases to check, but this is somewhat easier if you can use Notes/Domino 8 because there is a `Directory` class that takes care of that for you.

Answer (score 3):

What you are asking for is somewhat non-trival.

1. Database ACL. You need to determine the following.

   - Name in the ACL list.
   - Are they a person, server, group ?
   - if they are a group you need to read the Names.nsf
   - Do they have any roles?
2. Next you need to read every document in the database. In order to do this you will need the access rights to do so. So that would be reader access at least (if set on the document) as well as access to encrypted fields (again if set).

You can use the **NotesNoteCollection** class to iterate through design + documents.

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_NOTESNOTECOLLECTION_CLASS.html

Checking the design will allow you to read the Forms and see if they have a readers field and what values are set. After that you can check documents if the setting is not static for the related Form.

On a side point. If you are trying to diagnose a particular user against an application, you can use the following notes.ini settings.

```
DEBUG_THREADID=1
DEBUG_SERVERACL=2
```

This will print out on the Domino console everytime an ACL request is made. It will print Who is requesting, what level they requesting, what levels they have and what access they were given.

The debug is very verbose though so should only be used for diagnosing an issue and disabling when done.

Comment: I would skip reading the design collection and the Forms  Fields listed on Forms may or may not be present on documents.  They may or may not have the same type as listed on the Form.  It's only what's saved in the documents that counts when it comes down to it.  (Access controls on the form itself can block a user from displaying the document with the form; but they don't block programmatic access.)  Also, documents can contain additional readers or author fields that are not listed on any Form.

Comment: Well I mentioned it as there may be instances where no document is created yet for that form, but not having the list from the form may break functionality elsewhere (for whatever the OP plans to do).

Comment: I'm inferring that it's probably a security or compliance audit situation, which I think is the must usual reason people ask for this type of info.  But I could be wrong about that.

Comment: You are correct about the audit situation.  A report is needed to list who has read/right access to every document in database X.