# Extract IBM Notes View/Folder full ACL form Java API

Tags: lotus-notes, java

Is there any way to extract View or folder ACL using Java API? In case of Document (like [Extract Lotus Notes Document's complete ACL from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12732796/extract-lotus-notes-documents-complete-acl-from-java)) there is possibility to read item field `$Readers` or `$UpdateBy`, but there is no such fields in View object or any connected to users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get view's or folder's readers by [view.getReaders()](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_READERS_PROPERTY_VIEW_JAVA.html?lang=en):

```
  View view = db.getView("yourViewOrFolderName");
  Vector readers = view.getReaders();
```

*Update:*

Folders have updaters in addition. Unfortunately, there is no method getUpdaters.
Create a [NoteCollection](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_NOTESNOTECOLLECTION_CLASS_JAVA.html?lang=de), select view design elements only, iterate through views and find your folder and read item `$Updaters`.

Comment: And what about updaters? Readers is only ACL position possible to get?

Comment: View/Folders have only readers restrictions. The update right is given by database's ACL with Designer or Manager access.

Comment: So what about this case: http://imgur.com/6f9hhWo ? There are different updaters and readers. I've checked before and updater right also gives reader rights, doesn't it?

Comment: You are right. Folders have updaters in addition (not so views). I updated my answer.

Comment: How can I iterate over views in `NoteCollection`? In documentation examples they are using only `DxlExporter`. Is there any other way to read/iterate this?

Comment: Have a look at this example: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_EXAMPLES_REMOVE_METHOD_NC_JAVA.html?lang=de The while loop shows you how to get Documents (design elements in your case) from NoteCollection. (ignore the DXL stuff - it's not important here)

Comment: To get to views fields, I can also call `getUniversalID()` method on `View` object, and  fetch `Document` object from database with `getDocumentByUNID()`, and then do same as shown above. Is this way as same reliable as fetching views from `NoteCollection`?

Comment: That's an even better approach if you need to analyze just one folder. If you want to look at all folders then NoteCollection is probably easier.